ON basis for a certain subspace
Let $H$ be some separable Hilbert space and let $\{x_n\}_n$ be an orthogonal sequence in $H$ such that
$\sum_{n=1} ^\infty \lVert x_n \rVert^2 < \infty$
Let $H_1=\left\{ \sum_n \lambda_n x_n, \sum_n \lambda_n^2<\infty\right\}$,
then $H_1$ is a closed subspace of $H$. It is also separable and therefore it must have an ON basis. $\{\frac{x_n}{\lVert x_n \rVert} \}_n$ is an ON basis for the closed linear span of $\{x_n\}_n$, but that this is not same space as $H_1$ (as $\{x_n\}_n$ is not ON), how can I find a basis for $H_1$?

The subspace $H_1$ is not always a closed subspace of $H.$ For example let $x_n={1\over n}e_n,$ where ${e_n}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis of $H.$ Then $H_1$ is dense in $H$ as it contains every $e_n.$ In this case $H_1$ consists of all elements $x\in H$ such that $\sum|\langle x,x_n\rangle |^2n^2<\infty.$

To clarify @RyszardSzwarc ’s comment, in particular, $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}e_n = \sum_n x_n \notin H_1$. (Also, a slight correction. The correct criteria should be $\sum_n |\langle x, x_n\rangle|^2 n^4 < \infty$. Indeed, if $x = \sum_n x_n$, then $\sum_n |\langle x, x_n\rangle|^2 n^2 = \sum_n |\langle x_n, x_n\rangle|^2 n^2 = \sum_n \frac{1}{n^4} n^2 < \infty$, but $x \notin H_1$. Alternatively, $\sum_n |\langle x, e_n\rangle|^2 n^2 < \infty$ would also do.)

In fact, under the condition that $\sum_n |x_n|^2 < \infty$, $H_1$ is never closed (unless all but finitely many $x_n$ equal $0$). Indeed, $\sum_n x_n$ is in the closure of $H_1$ but not in $H_1$ itself.
